# Foreach implode issue

Tags: php

I have this piece of code that gets the values of meta boxes in WordPress.

```
$guiones  = rwmb_meta( 'mb_guionistas', array( 'multiple' => true) );
$pieces = array();

foreach ($guiones as $item) {
    $pieces[] = '<a href="' . bloginfo('url') . '/?p=' . $item . '" title="">' . get_the_title( $item ) . '</a>';
}

echo implode(', ', $pieces);
```

The problem is that the result it doesn't just show a comma separated values but adds the blog URL at the beginning.

I'm pretty sure is something related to how `$pieces` is structured.

Can you see any problem on the code?

[image]

Attached the results of adding 2 values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to:

```
<?php
$guiones  = rwmb_meta( 'mb_guionistas', array( 'multiple' => true) );
$pieces = array();

foreach ($guiones as $item) {
    $pieces [] = '<a href="' . get_bloginfo('url') . '/?p=' . $item . '" title="">' . get_the_title( $item ) . '</a>';
}

echo implode(', ', $pieces);
?>
```

`bloginfo()` echos values while `get_bloginfo()` returns values.